# how to convert HTML having Unicode to PDF using PHP?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I’m trying to convert HTML code having Nepali Unicode to PDF format. But I’ve been unable to get exact Unicode format which I’ve designed in the HTML page.

Comment: this is a similar post to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php/434827#434827